# Speed up finding matches between two dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am working on a spatial analysis problem using Python 2.7. I have a dictionary `edges` representing edges in a graph, where key is the edgeID and the value is the start/end points:

```
{e1: [(12.8254, 55.3880), (12.8343, 55.3920)], 
e2: [(12.8254, 55.3880), (12.8235, 55.3857)], 
e3: [(12.2432, 57.1120), (12.2426, 57.1122)]}
```

And I have another dictionary `nodes` where key is the nodeID and the value is the node coordinates:

```
{n14: (12.8254, 55.3880), 
n15: (12.8340, 55.3883), 
n16: (12.8235, 55.3857), 
n17: (12.8343, 55.3920)}
```

I need to get a list which will look like (the 'n' and 'e' in the keys is just for illustration purposes for this question, I have integers there):

```
[(e1,n14,n17),(e2,n14,n16)..]
```

That is, I iterate over the edges dict, take every key, find the value that exist in the `nodes` dict and add to a tuple. This is how I do it now:

```
edgesList = []
for featureId in edges:
        edgeFeatureId = [k for k, v in edges.iteritems() if k == featureId][0]
        edgeStartPoint = [k for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if v == edges[featureId][0]][0]#start point
        edgeEndPoint = [k for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if v == edges[featureId][1]][0]#end point
        edgesList.append((edgeFeatureId,edgeStartPoint,edgeEndPoint))
```

This is working, but is very slow when working with large datasets (with 100K edges and 90K nodes it takes ca 10 mins).

I've figured out how to use a list comprehension while getting each of the tuple's items, but is it possible to get my 3 list comprehensions into one to avoid iterating the edges with the `for` loop (if this will speed things up)?

**Is there another way I can build such a list faster?**

***UPDATE***

As Martin suggested, I've inverted my nodes dict:

```
nodesDict = dict((v,k) for k,v in oldnodesDict.iteritems())
```

having node coordinates tuple as key and the nodeID as value. Unfortunately, it did not speed up the lookup process (here is the updated code - I flipped the `k` and `v` for `edgeStartPoint` and `edgeEndPoint`):

```
edgesList = []
for featureId in edges:
        edgeFeatureId = [k for k, v in edges.iteritems() if k == featureId][0]
        edgeStartPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][0]][0]#start point
        edgeEndPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][1]][0]#end point
        edgesList.append((edgeFeatureId,edgeStartPoint,edgeEndPoint))
```

Comment: Could you create and object representing an edge? You could overload equal function or other function to ease working with this data structure?

Comment: @Marcin, did you mean creating a class for the edge object? I was hoping to be able to do some kind of smart dictionary matching but could find anything appropriate.

Comment: Yep, an Edge class. It seem that It could simply your code and operations on the edges.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. The operation I am trying to speed up is the last one I will do in Python, all the data processing that occurs before happens in seconds, it is just the last part that takes so much time. I would like to avoid creating class for the Edge as I won't be using it for anything else...

Comment: so your problem is the append()? then try using a deque as `edgesList`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque
"Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Comment: Why are you using `iteritems()` everywhere, the point of a dictionary is key based lookup, with `iteritems()` you have O(N) performance on each lookup. Either re-arrange your data to allow lookup by key, or switch to a binary-search-tree type structure which will at least give Olog(n).

Comment: @user3467349, thanks for pointing this out. I believe this is what Martin mentioned in the answer accepted by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are matching based on the coordinates, your nodes dictionary should be inverted.

That is, it should look like so:

```
{(12.8254, 55.3880): n14, 
(12.8340, 55.3883): n15, 
(12.8235, 55.3857): n16, 
(12.8343, 55.3920): n17}
```

This way, when you are iterating over your edges, you have a very quick look-up to find the corresponding nodes:

```
edgesList = []
for featureId in edges:
    coordinates = edges[featureId]
    c0, c1 = coordinates

    n0 = nodes[c0]
    n1 = nodes[c1]

    edgesList.append((featureId, n0, n1))
```

Remember, that dictionaries are extremely quick at finding the corresponding value for any given key. So quick that in the average case, the speed of the lookup [should barely change](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) given that the dictionary is of size 1 or size 1 million.

Comment: Martin, what is the coordinates variables? I don't understand how `edgeFeatureId, coordinates = e` works.

Comment: `x, y = [1, 2]` means x will become 1 and y will become 2. You need to use the code I supplied, not just invert the dictionary.

Comment: I misunderstand your original code slightly. Updated my answer - it should be more clear now.

Comment: with `'coordinates = edges[featureId]` it makes sense. I've just realized that I was searching through the values with `==` instead of referring to a value based on the key with `dict[key]`. Thanks for pointing this out, it works correctly and very fast.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out in your comments, the problem is the last operation `edgesList.append((id,start,end))`.

this seems to be a data type problem: a big dictionary slows down by design. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256913/improving-performance-of-very-large-dictionary-in-python).

but gladly you can use a double-ended-queue (deque) instead. [deque documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque): "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

in code it means you initialize a deque and append to it with high performance.

```
edgesList = deque() 
for featureId in edges:
        edgeFeatureId = [k for k, v in edges.iteritems() if k == featureId][0]
        edgeStartPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][0]][0]#start point
        edgeEndPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][1]][0]#end point
        edgesList.append((edgeFeatureId,edgeStartPoint,edgeEndPoint))
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. For which dict should I use a set instead? And how would I refer to the set "key" when searching for the node? Any code snippet?

Comment: ah sorry a set uses values only. i'm a bit tired this morning :D i think about it again

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example data here is an example I think might work:

```
edges = {
    1: [(12.8254, 55.3880), (12.8343, 55.3920)],
    2: [(12.8254, 55.3880), (12.8235, 55.3857)],
    3: [(12.2432, 57.1120), (12.2426, 57.1122)]}
nodes = {
    14: (12.8254, 55.3880),
    15: (12.8340, 55.3883),
    16: (12.8235, 55.3857),
    17: (12.8343, 55.3920)}
reverseNodes=dict((v,k) for k, v in nodes.iteritems())
edgesList=[]
for k,v in edges.items():
    edgesList.append( 
            (k,
             reverseNodes.get(v[0], -1),
             reverseNodes.get(v[1], -1)))
```

Maybe there is something I do not understand with your building of the `edgesList` but I think this looks simpler and faster.

Again based on your example code, this is what's consuming your cpu-time:

```
edgeFeatureId = [k for k, v in edges.iteritems() if k == featureId][0]
edgeStartPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][0]][0]#start point
edgeEndPoint = [v for k, v in nodes.iteritems() if k == edges[featureId][1]][0]#end point
```

This exists inside a for-loop, so for every edge you:

- Iterate one extra time over the list of edges (to find the edge id which you already have)
- Iterate twice over the nodes list to find start and end points (you don't need this any longer since we figured out how to get direct-lookup with the reverseNodes-dict).

So with your datasizes you should get roughly 100000*(100000+90000+90000) or O(n^2) operations which is a lot more than just one pass over the edges (100000 or O(n))